# ASP.NET Web API, EF Core + Identity library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-webapi

I am building a hospital management system using ASP.NET Web API and EF Core.

I have these tables:

1. Appointments
2. Beds
3. Departments
4. Invoices
5. MedicalHistories
6. MedicalTests
7. Prescriptions

I have used ASP.NET Identity library for authentication, authorization and role management.

And I have Patient, Doctor, Admin and Nurse as roles in this system.

Each user by default if not assigned a role will be created with Patient role.

I want to link user with role of Patient and Doctor to the `Appointment` and `Prescriptions` tables, how can I achieve this?

I have tried to create separate tables for each roles described above and i don't think this is the best way to go about it since each time we add a new role we'd need to create a new table.

Answer (score 1):

> I have used ASP.NET Identity library for authentication, authorization
> and role management.

Well, your question is so elaborative and hard to answer within one question. Apart from this, it would be nicer, if you could share few of your implementation how have you tried and where are you stuck in.

However, instead of writting the full solution, I am assisting you partially, once you would successfully implement this, you can ask new question, so that we can solve it incrementally which would be more reasonable.

> I want to link user with role of Patient and Doctor to the Appointment
> and Prescriptions tables, how can I achieve this?

Regarding Appointment and Prescriptions  table, first of all think the real scenario, when you confirm an appointment, there should be a patientId who is also a user, and appointment set with a doctor who is also a user.

So while you would design your model you should consider this scenario, So, you can do as following:

```
public class Appointment
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime AppointmentDate { get; set; }
    public Guid PatinetId { get; set; } //Is a user of patient role which we can found in AspNetUserRoles
    public Guid DoctorId { get; set; } //Is a user of doctor role which we can found in AspNetUserRoles

}
```

**Note:** Same goes for prescription as well. Becasue, prescription has provided by the doctor and given to a patient. So, when you would insert data into Appointment and Prescription table, you should query on both AspNetUsers and AspNetUserRoles table in order to get the specific user and his role.

Let's have look in implementation:

First of all you should insert all of your role into AspNetRoles table. Below class and table is for your reference.

Model:

```
public static class UserRoles
{
    public const string Patient = "Patient";
    public const string Doctor = "Doctor";
    public const string Admin = "Admin";
    public const string Nurse = "Nurse";

}
```

**Note:** Can also be a list or enum type.

[image]

View Model:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Full name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Full name is required")]
    public required string FullName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Email address")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email address is required")]
    public required string EmailAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public required string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Confirm password is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match")]
    public required string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Inherite IdentityUser Class:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    

}
```

Controller:

```
public class UserRegistrationController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;

    public UserRegistrationController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager, ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _context = context;
    }
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public IActionResult RegisterUser()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost("RegisterNewUser")]
    public async Task<IActionResult>  RegisterNewUser(RegisterViewModel registerViewModel)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid || registerViewModel.FullName == null || registerViewModel.EmailAddress == null)
        {
            TempData["warning"] = "Incorrect sign up! Please enter correct information and try again.";
        }



        var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(registerViewModel.EmailAddress!);
        if (user != null)
        {
            TempData["Error"] = "This email address is already in use";

        }

        var createNewUser = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            Email = registerViewModel.EmailAddress,
            UserName = registerViewModel.FullName
        };
        var newUserResponse = await _userManager.CreateAsync(createNewUser, registerViewModel.Password!);

        if (newUserResponse.Succeeded)
        {
            await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(createNewUser, UserRoles.Patient);
        }
        

        if (newUserResponse.Errors != null)
        {
            List<string> errorDetails = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in newUserResponse.Errors)
            {
                errorDetails.Add(item.Description);
            }
            ViewBag.errorDetails = errorDetails;
        }


        return View("RegisterUser");
    }
```

**Note:** Based on your scenario, you can set a conditional while adding new user, I am adding Patient role here: `userManager.AddToRoleAsync(createNewUser, UserRoles.Patient);`

Output:

[image]

Note: Its a huge implementation, try up to this part, if you enounter any issue, feel free to ask new question. In addition, please [refer to this official document for asp.net core identity implementation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-configuration?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: I like how you guided him with a step-by-step.

Comment: Thank you **@PauloSantos** for checking on this, actually, its a big implementation, just assisting him by splitting into small part that might help him to grab the point.